# SELECT depending on calculation from adjacent row

Tags: mysql

I have a table of stock prices that is quite long. I want to select rows where price changed more than some amount.

Something like :

```
SELECT * from msft WHERE difference([price on given day], [price day before]) > x;
```

bonus : no primary keys

Comment: Yeah, just select something from somewhere and join it to something. Should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

For me the better way is create an precalculated column, you can actualize it with code or a trigger,
in this new column with the difference put index for better performance.

Your query work fine:

```
SELECT * from msft WHERE (priceongivenday-pricedaybefore) > amount;
```